# Fixing sub-menu to show when tabbing through or on hover

Tags: html

Hello I am currently facing a issue where I want my sub menu to show when i tab to it or hover over it on focus. I want to remove the arrow so its not clickable to show the sub menu on both menus but u can tab or hover over it to show the submenu.
Also how would i align everything properly it is not overlapping the header.

```js
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


$(function() {
    
    var currentItem = "";
    
    $( 'nav li').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('handling menu click event: ', $(this).attr('id'), ": ", (currentItem ? currentItem.attr('id'): "") );
        
        $(this).closest('nav').find('li, span').removeClass('active');
        
        if ( $(this).hasClass( 'menu-item-has-children' ) ) {
            $(this).find('> span').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        
        console.log('done setting active');
        if ( $(this).hasClass('menu-item-has-ancestor') ) {
            console.log('setting parent active ', $(this).parent().closest('span.menu-item-text'));
            $(this).parent().closest('li').find('span.menu-item-text').addClass('active');
            e.stopPropagation();
            
        } else if ($(this).hasClass( 'menu-item-has-children' ) ) {
            console.log('setting toggle for children');
            var degrees = 90;
            var submenu = $(this).children('ul');
            var arrow   = $(this).find('button.menu-item-expand');
            if ( submenu.hasClass( 'menu-list-toggle-closed' ) ) {
                console.log('removing closed');
                submenu.removeClass( 'menu-list-toggle-closed' );
                degrees = 270;
                
            } else {
                console.log('adding closed');
                submenu.addClass( 'menu-list-toggle-closed' );
            }
            console.log('arrow: ', arrow);
            if ( arrow ) {
                arrow.css('transform', ( 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)' ) );
            }
            
        } else {
            console.log('should not have to deal with this as a page would have loaded');
            $('nav li > ul').each(function(idx) {
                if ( ! ( $(this).hasClass( 'menu-list-toggle-closed' ) ) ) {
                    $(this).addClass( 'menu-list-toggle-closed' );
                    var arrow   = $(this).parent().find('button.menu-item-expand');
                    if ( arrow ) {
                        arrow.css('transform', ( 'rotate(90deg)' ) );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        
        currentItem = $(this);
    });
    
});
```

```css
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : May 24, 2018, 12:07:14 PM
    Author     : djrice
*/

.main-navigation {
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}

.main-navigation a,
.main-navigation a:visited,
.main-navigation span.menu-item-text {
    display: inline-block;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    padding: .5em 1em .5em 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3e3d3c;
}

.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-navigation > ul {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.main-navigation li {
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation .active {
    background-color: #c5ddfc;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li:focus > ul {
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;  /* flex */
    top: 2.5em;
    background-color: #e8eaeb;
    /*background-color: #c5ddfc;*/
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
}

.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children {
    /*background-color: #e8eaeb;*/
}

.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a {
    padding-right: 0em;
}

.main-navigation .menu-list-toggle-closed {
    display:none;
}

.main-navigation button.menu-item-expand {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .25em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
?>

<nav id="primary-nav" class="main-navigation">
    <ul id="menu-item-1" class="menu-top">
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item">
            <a href="/page-about_the_collection.php">
               <span>About the<br />Collection</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item">
            <a href="/xtf/search?brand=plastics&collection=plastics&objectType=Artifact">
                Objects
            </a>
        </li>
         <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item">
            <a href="/xtf/search?brand=plastics&collection=plastics&objectType=findingaid&sort=title">
                Manuscripts
            </a>
        </li>
         <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item">
            <a href="/xtf/search?brand=plastics&collection=plastics&objectType=catalog&sort=title">
                Books &amp; Journals
            </a>
        </li>
         <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item">
            <li class="nav6 LOGO"><h1 class="body_header-logo"><a href="/" class="header-logo noborder">
                The Plastics Collection
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
            <span class="menu-item-text">
                <a href="/page-the_history.php"> History & People </a>
            <button class="menu-item-expand">&#062;</button>
            </span>
            <ul id="menu-item-7" class="menu-list menu-list-toggle-closed">
                <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/page-the_history.php">
                        The&nbsp;History
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/page-essays.php">
                        Essays
                    </a>
                </li>
                 <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/page-timeline.php">
                        Timeline
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/xtf/search?brand=plastics&collection=plastics&entityType=person&sort=title&letterFilter=AA">
                       People
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/xtf/search?brand=plastics&collection=plastics&entityType=corporateBody&sort=title&letterFilter=AA">
                        Companies
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
                <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
            <span class="menu-item-text">
                <a href="page-materials.php">  Materials </a>
            <button class="menu-item-expand">&#062;</button>
            </span>
            <ul id="menu-item-13" class="menu-list menu-list-toggle-closed">
                <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/page-materials.php">
                        Materials
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-has-ancestor">
                    <a href="/page-processes.php">
                        Processes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item">
            <a href="/page-resources.php">
                Other Resources
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```